# Is there a way to enable a scrollbar in an AnyChart graphics object?

Tags: anychart

I'm currently making an AnyChart graphics item with multiple graphs contained within a table. I've reached an issue where there are too many rows of data in this table and I'd like it to continue on the graphic with the option for the user to scroll down. Is this possible?

Comment: We'd like to clarify a few details. Do you want to scroll the table which rows contain graphics? Does this table fill the whole <div> in your HTML?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've managed to get something like this working now. The AnyChart graphic is now nested in two DIVs, with the parent of AnyChart graphic holding and overflow-y: scroll property. The AnyChart graphic is set to a higher height. This has enabled native browser scrolling effect that works quite well.

Answer (score 0):

The AnyChart graphic is now nested in two DIVs, with the parent of AnyChart graphic holding and overflow-y: scroll property. The AnyChart graphic is set to a higher height. This has enabled native browser scrolling effect that works quite well.

Answer (score 0):

Now I see, great! I think the following example may help you. It contains tables placed on stages, but it works with graphics well. The idea to set overflow to the container and define stage height. Try to scroll the table in the middle of this sample.

```js
anychart.onDocumentReady(function () {

        var stage = null;

        //array for common padding settings
        var padding = [0, 10, 0, 10];

        //initial create table
        createTable();
        
                        //create table with headers
        stageHeaders = anychart.graphics.create("headers");
    //create standalone table
    tableHeaders = anychart.standalones.table();
    var headers = [];
    headers.push(['Static header', 'static header']);
        tableHeaders.contents(headers);
        tableHeaders.getCol(0).width(100);
        tableHeaders.container(stageHeaders).draw();
        
                stageBottom = anychart.graphics.create("bottom");
    //create standalone table
    tableBot = anychart.standalones.table();
                        var axes = [];
    axes.push(['Static bottom', 'Static bottom']);
        tableBot.contents(axes);
        tableBot.getCol(0).width(100);
        tableBot.container(stageBottom).draw();
       
        //create table
        function createTable() {
            if (stage !== null) {
                stage.dispose();
            }

            stage = anychart.graphics.create("container");

            //create standalone table
            table = anychart.standalones.table();

            var tableContent = [];
            tableContent.push(['Content', 'Content']);

            for (var j = 0; j<20; j++) {
                    tableContent.push(['Content', 'Content']);
            }

            tableContent.push(['THE END', null]);

            table.contents(tableContent);

                //adjust table appearance
                table.getRow(0).height(45);

                for (var k=0; k<table.rowsCount(); k++) {
                    table.getRow(k).height(45);
                }

                table.getCol(0).width(100);
                table.getCol(0).border().left('white');
                table.getCol(0).border().top('white');
                table.getCol(0).border().bottom('white');
                table.getCol(1).border().right('white');
                table.getCol(1).border().top('white');
                table.getCol(1).border().bottom('white');
                table.getCol(1).cellPadding(padding);
                table.vAlign('middle');

            //render the table
            table.container(stage).draw();
      stage.height(1000);
        }
    });
```

```css
html, body {
            position: relative;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }

        #container {
            position: relative;
            width: 100%;
            height: 65%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            overflow-y: scroll;
        }
                #headers {
            position: relative;
            width: 100%;
            height: 10%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
                        #bottom {
            position: relative;
            width: 100%;
            height: 10%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
```

```html
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/8.0.1/js/anychart-base.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/8.0.1/js/anychart-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/8.0.1/js/anychart-exports.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/8.0.1/js/anychart-bullet.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/8.0.1/js/anychart-table.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/8.0.1/css/anychart-ui.min.css"/>
    
<div id="headers"></div>
<div id="container"></div>
<div id="bottom"></div>
```